# Meteor accounts password: TypeError: Accounts.setPassword is not a function

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using: 
Meteor Version 1.8, 
accounts-password@1.5.1

When invoking:

```
  Meteor.methods({
    setPassword(newPassword, userId) {
      check(userId, String);
      check(newPassword, String);
      if(Meteor.user().isAdmin){
        Accounts.setPassword(userId, newPassword);
      }
    },
  });
```

by

```
Meteor.call('setPassword', password, this.userId);
```

i get this error:
`Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'setPassword' TypeError: Accounts.setPassword is not a function` 
but the password is still set...

Comment: Is your method in a 'server' folder? If not, I think the setPassword should be within a server segment, i.e.  'if (Meteor.isServer) {..//your setPassword method}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor methods can run on both server and client side ([see here](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#call-lifecycle)). Here the error is coming from the client side : `simulating the effect` means the client is trying to compute an optimistic answer to your query to the server.

The Accounts object is available both client and server side, but I bet that the Accounts.setPassword function is only available in the server for security reasons.

To avoid the error, you can either : Place the meteor method definition in a server-only folder [see here](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) (like in this file `app_code/imports/api/accounts/server/methods.js`), or wrap it with `if(Meteor.isServer)` [see here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-isServer) as such:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.methods({
        setPassword(newPassword, userId) {
            check(userId, String);
            check(newPassword, String);
            if(Meteor.user().isAdmin){
                Accounts.setPassword(userId, newPassword);
            }
        },
    });
}
```